# How to apply a Char function via map to a [Char]

Tags: string, haskell, char

I'm working on a very specific question however I've stumbled upon a logical error that I just cannot seem to solve.

Basically I have a function that that takes a char and returns it as a string with a space appended. From there I am required to map that function to a string and return a string of strings, each as a char with a space appended.

I have attempted so many different things I don't even recall what gives me the least errors anymore. After staring at this for two *sad* hours I could really use some input.

```
addSpace :: Char -> [Char]
addSpace t = [t,' ']

addSpaces :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
addSpaces y = map addSpace[????????]
```

The main issue I have is, no matter what I put into the 'map addSpace' function I get type errors.

I apologize if this question is way simpler than I think it is. I'm just having a rough time.
Thanks in advance! I have really appreciated the help I have received in the past from the Haskell community on stack overflow.

Comment: Try `map addSpace y`.

Comment: @melpomene I swear that was the first thing I tried... but it worked... Thank you so much. I can't believe it was so simple.

Comment: You could also have `addSpaces = map addSpace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass in `y` as the second argument to `map`.

```
addSpaces y = map addSpace y
```

Or, you could remove the argument `y`, and have the argument passed in implicitly (pointfree style).

```
addSpaces = map addSpace
```